# Vue-Router working but not transform router-link to anchor tag

Tags: html, vuejs2, vue-router

`vue-router` works well, but `<router-link to="/path">Link</router-link>` element isn't rendering to `<a href="/path">Link</a>` but just to plain text `Link`. Let me show you my code:

**index.html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Content -->
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
const Vue = require('vue');
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

//routing stuff
import GMap from './components/g-map.vue';
import Home from './components/home.vue';

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
   { path: '/', component: Home },
   { path: '/g-map', component: GMap }
  ]
});

new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#wrapper');
```

**home.vue**

```
<template id="home">
    <div>
        <!-- some stuff -->
        <router-link to="/g-map">Link</router-link>
        <a href="#" @click="testVueRoute">Another link</a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    testVueRoute() {
      this.$router.push({ path: "g-map" });
    }
  }
};
```

**g-map.vue**

```
<template id="g-map">
  <div>SOME CONTENT FROM G-MAP</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>
```

`home` component is rendered at start (because has a path `/` in routing) and on the loaded site I can see **text** "Link" and clickable link "Another link". Source of the site looks like this:

```
<div>
    <!-- some stuff -->
    Link
    <a href="#">Another link</a>
</div>
```

Clicking on the text "Link" does nothing, cliking on the "Another link" call successfull `testVueRoute` method and content of `g-map` component appear.

Vue-route do a job because `this.$router.push({ path: "g-map" });` works well, but why the `<router-link to="/path">Link</router-link>` element is not rendering to `a` tag?

Comment: What is the output rendered on the website? I.e. what does the source give you for `<router-link>`? Also, try using `g-map` instead of `/g-map` while adding `name: 'G-map'` (or whatever your component name is) to `routes[ ]`

Comment: @Bram The output rendered on the website is plain text `Link` (without any tag). Removing slash from `/g-map` nothing changed.

Comment: You did add a name for each route in `routes[ ]`?

Comment: Yes, I tried with route names, but there was no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this topic](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue2-vue-router-router-link-not-transform-into-anchor-tag/74030/10?u=zmuszony) the solution is updating `vue` and `vue-router` package to newest version (probably you have to update `vue-template-compiler` too).

Answer (score 1):

Include the **tag** attribute within your router link - like so: `<router-link tag="a" to="/g-map">Link</router-link>`

Comment: Nothing changed :(

Comment: If you're using vue-devtools, visit the `/g-map` link directly from the browser and see if the route shows up there.

Comment: I have vue-devtools and there is 2 paths in `Routing` tab - `/` and `/g-map`. I'm not sure what do you mean by "visit the /g-map link directly from the browser"? Just concatenate website url with /g-map (like lcalhost:8080/g-map)?

Comment: Yes. But the route shows up in devtools, so it seems to be registered. Have you tried `<router-link exact tag="a" to="/g-map">Link</router-link>` or `<router-link tag="a" :to="{ path: 'g-map' }">Link</router-link>`? Also, just so we can eliminate some variables, set up a `router-link` for the `home` path. Does that work?

Comment: Unfortunatelly none of these working. `<router-link>` element was stil rendered to plain text, not to anchor tag.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this. `<router-link :to="{ name: 'your name here' }" class="btn btn-primary">Create Catgeory</router-link>`

And in app js add name like this.

```
{
      name: 'home',
      path: '/',
      component: HomeComponent
}
```